# Unable to get data from website that redirects to another

Tags: python, html, python-requests

I'm trying to get data from chatzy.com, specifically one of the rooms in it. For example, take http://us19.chatzy.com/72966652423259 - that's the URL for the room's inside, but if you try to get data from it with python, using the request library (code below) instead of giving you this:

unimportant html unimportant html:

```
<P class="a"><B style="color:#000000;">William</B>: test</P>
<P class="a"><B style="color:#000000;">William</B>: test1</P>
<P class="a"><B style="color:#000000;">William</B>: test2</P>
<P class="a"><B style="color:#000000;">William</B>: test3</P>
<P class="a"><B style="color:#000000;">William</B>: test4</P>
<P class="a"><B style="color:#000000;">William</B>: test5</P>
```

It gives me the html for view-source:http://www.chatzy.com/72966652423259 which is just viewing the front page.
I don't really care about the front page - my ultimate intentions are to be able to read user + message at every time. If who knows more about Python than I do can help, it would be much appreciated.

Code is very basic at the moment, just retrieving the data from the site:

```
import requests
z = requests.get("http://www.chatzy.com/72966652423259")
content = str(z.content) # because z.content is binary
print(content)
```

Comment: `Requests` can handle client-side redirects just fine.  Thus it appears that you are looking at a server-side redirect, which is going to be rather cumbersome to troubleshoot.  The site uses one or more of your IP address, your Referrer, your cookies, Javascript, and possibly additional techniques I can't think of right now to make sure you navigate the site (what they think is) properly, rather than allowing you to go straight to a page.  You have to figure out which mechanism(s) they use and follow their rules.

Comment: I doubt you are going to find anybody here who is going to volunteer to do that work for you, but if you can show us how far you can get on your own, it's likely that someone can help you connect the dots to get you there.